# Filtering out conditioned arrays from a matrix

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

In Sweden there is a football (soccer) betting game where you try to find the outcome of 13 matches. Since each match can have a home win, a draw or an away team win this leads to 3**13=1594323 possible outcomes. You win if you have 10 to 13 matches correct.  You don't want this to occur when a lot of other people also have high scores since the prize sum is divided among all winners. This is the background to the more generic question that I'm looking for an answer to: how to find all arrays that differ by at least x elements from a given array within the matrix (in this case 1594323*13).

The first obvious idea that came to my mind was to have 13 nested for loops and compare one array at the time. However, I'm using this problem as a training session to learn myself Python programming. Python is not the optimal tool for this kind of task and I could turn to C to get a faster program but I'm interested in the best algorithm as such.

In Python I tried the nested for loop method up to 10 matches, then the execution time got too long, 5 seconds on the netbook I'm using. For each added match, the execution time went up tenfold.

Another approach would be to use a database and that might be the solution but I'm curious what the fastest way of solving this kind of problem is. I haven't been successful googling this problem, maybe because it's hard to use the correct description of the problem in a short search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a recursive solution that terminates in about 5 seconds on my machine, when given an `x` value of 0 (the worst case).  For `x` values of 10 and above it's nearly instantaneous.

```
def arrays_with_differences(arr, x):
    if x > len(arr):
        return []

    if len(arr) == 0:
        return [[]]

    smallColl1 = arrays_with_differences(arr[:len(arr)-1], x)
    smallColl2 = arrays_with_differences(arr[:len(arr)-1], x-1)

    last = arr[len(arr)-1]
    altLast1 = (last + 1) % 3
    altLast2 = (last + 2) % 3

    result = [smallArr + [last] for smallArr in smallColl1]
    result.extend([smallArr + [altLast1] for smallArr in smallColl2])
    result.extend([smallArr + [altLast2] for smallArr in smallColl2])
    return result

result = arrays_with_differences([1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], 4)
print(len(result))
```

Comment: Besides running much faster it is also a very elegant solution, thanks!